# Log to Ubuntu with wsl

Tags: ubuntu, boot, login, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed Ubuntu on WSL 2.0.
When I'm in the command line I am logged as `useradd@NAMEOFMYPC:~$`

The `whoami` command answer **useradd** .

The `adduser` command asks me **useradd**'s password and

`apropos user` and `man` didn't help me.

How to properly add a user and start using the system ? Thanks.

Comment: What's your actual problem ?

Comment: you're already using the system.

Comment: You mean I accidentally created a user called "useradd" . Then why I cant access to /root ,  /home etc.. ?

Comment: not only did you create that user, you've (probably as root) also switched to it. Don't. just start a fresh WSL session, and you're good to go. You don't have to add any users.